# dojo.io.script.get caching

Tags: caching, dojo

I'm loading data using dojo.io.script.get. Size of each request can be big and I need to issue lots of them.

Question is, after data loaded and later dismissed is it cached by browser?

In other words, when I load some data that have content "myFunc('blah blah blah')". It will execute myFunc function. What happens to the browser memory after execution? If I say load it 100 times and size of each string within myFunc is say 1GB, will browser run out of memory?

Thanks.
Andrei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things I have learned about Dojo is that the source code is a great reference.

My quick inspection of dojo/io/script.js shows that there is some logic involving dead code tags and destroying script tags so I guess it should protect against the memory leaks you mention. (Of course, you should always test this kind of stuff yourself, just to be sure).

Comment: Yes it does look like dojo.io.script performs some cleanup. Thank you.